# I would like to know how to tie textviev with part of button / how i can put textview on the button?

Tags: android, button

I want to create button with `text = "SomeText"` on center of this button and "0" on right part of button. Where "0" is the Counter and when I click this button Counter++ increments, and becomes "1"... I would like to know how to tie textviev with "right part of button" ?
like this http://cs617622.vk.me/v617622052/10146/Ln_S82lCbYA.jpg

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_menu"
android:onClick="but1_Count"
android:text="SomeText"
android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
android:textSize="100dp" />
```

Comment: хули вы минусуете, волки?

Comment: You have already asked this question. Please don't create new duplicate questions - edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

instead of button try to implement  a text 
then set background in xml
and then increament the value

mytext.settext("Some text"+"1");